# How to config MAC(message authentication code) using curl command

Tags: linux, sftp, curl

I want to download file via curl with sftp, like this

*curl --insecure "sftp://1.1.1.1:22" --user 'root:123123'*

and the sftp server make a security config(/etc/ssh/sshd_config, *MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256*), so curl can't make connection with server, there is error logs in message.log

*fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com server hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256 [preauth]*

how can I config the mac with curl?

Comment: curl use the libssh2 to execute sftp operation, and old libssh2 don't support new HMAC algorithm, and I compile curl with the newest libssh, it works

Answer (score 0):

1.compile openssl

./config -fPIC no-shared no-threads no-asm --prefix=/usr1/local/ssl

2.compile libssh2

./configure --prefix=/usr1/local/ssh2 --exec-prefix=/usr1/local/ssh2 --includedir=/usr1/local/ssh2 --disable-examples-build

3.need move include file location to adjust the curl requirement

mkdir /usr1/local/ssh2/include

mv /usr1/local/ssh2/*.h /usr1/local/ssh2/include/

4.compile curl

./configure --prefix=/usr1/local/curl --with-libssh2=/usr1/local/ssh2 --with-ssl=/usr1/local/ssl

5.it works